# No such file or directory in ubuntu

Tags: nosuchfileexception

Receiving following error stack:

> dhruv@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/bin$ cd
>
> dhruv@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ cd Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin
>
> dhruv@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin$
>   sbin/start-dfs.sh
>
> -bash: sbin/start-dfs.sh: No such file or directory
>
> dhruv@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin$
>   sbin/start-all.sh
>
> -bash: sbin/start-all.sh: No such file or directory
>
> dhruv@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin$ ssh
>   localhost
>
> Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
>
> Last login: Thu Oct  8 10:50:16 2015 from localhost
>
> dhruv@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~$ cd Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin
>
> dhruv@dhruv-Inspiron-N5010:~/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin$
>   sbin/start-dfs.sh
>
> -bash: sbin/start-dfs.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: So what's your question? (You probably want to try './start-dfs.sh'.)

Comment: Yes, I wanna start the daemon nodes but it is showing no such file or directory

Comment: Are the files there or not? (Check with 'ls')

Comment: Yes these files are present.

Answer (score 0):

You already changed to the sbin directory, so now you have to use

> ./start-dfs.sh

instead of

> sbin/start-dfs.sh

Comment: The standard way of telling "It's working" is to accept the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

start-all.sh is a file not a directory,
to run such files you must use ' ./ ' before the executable file,

try :
`./start-all.sh`